# Azure AD - Delete Users after XYZ since last sign in date

Tags: powershell, azure-active-directory

We are in the process of building a script, the overall functionality is there, but it doesnt appears to be executing correctly.

```
Select-MgProfile beta

$usertype = "Guest" #Enter Guest or Member
$Days = "1" #Enter number in days
$TodaysDate = Get-Date
$DaysOld = (Get-Date).AddDays($Days)
$users = Get-MgUser -all | Where-Object {$_.UserType -eq $usertype}

foreach ($User in $users) {
            if ($user.SignInActivity.LastSignInDateTime -ne $null){
                $Signin = $User.SignInActivity.LastSignInDateTime
                $LastLogin = New-TimeSpan -Start $Signin -End $TodaysDate -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | Select Name -ExpandProperty Days | Out-String 
                    if ($lastLogin -gt $Days){
                        Remove-MgUser -UserId $User.Id -WhatIf #REMOVE BEFORE PROD
                        Write-Host $user.DisplayName
                    }
                }
             }
```

When executing the last 3 lines seperatly it is all good, however when running as a full script it wont remove the user (ignoring the -whatif)

Any ideas?

Comment: Just do `$LastLogin = (New-TimeSpan -Start $Signin -End $TodaysDate).Days` and define $Days as integer, not a string `$Days = 1`. Also, better use `if ($user.SignInActivity.LastSignInDateTime)` instead of comparing to `$null`, but if you really feel you want that, write `$null` as the LHS of the equation

Comment: I also see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/signinactivity?view=graph-rest-beta#properties) that `LastSignInDateTime` is a _timestamp that represents date and time information using ISO 8601 format and is always in UTC time._
That means you need to convert that to a local DateTime object using `$Signin = [datetime]$($User.SignInActivity.LastSignInDateTime)` and seeing that this property is actually a string, better test if the property exists using `if (![string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($user.SignInActivity.LastSignInDateTime))`

Answer (score 0):

Continuing from my comments:

- property `LastSignInDateTime` is a string in ISO 8601 format and is always in UTC time, so you need to convert that to a (local) DateTime object
- when calculating `$LastLogin`, you want that to be an integer value holding the number of days, so just use it in creating a TimeStamp and get the `.Days` property from that

```
Select-MgProfile beta

$usertype = "Guest" #Enter Guest or Member
$Days =  1 #Enter number in days
$TodaysDate = Get-Date
$users = Get-MgUser -all | Where-Object {$_.UserType -eq $usertype}

foreach ($User in $users) {
    # LastSignInDateTime is a string in ISO 8601 format and is always in UTC time
    # see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/signinactivity?view=graph-rest-beta#properties
    $lastTime = $user.SignInActivity.LastSignInDateTime
    if (![string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($lastTime)){
        # this will convert the UTC time to a LOCAL DateTime object.
        # if you want to compare to UTC, use $Signin = ([datetime]$lastTime).ToUniversalTime()
        # but then you also need to use $TodaysDate = (Get-Date).ToUniversalTime()
        $Signin    = [datetime]$lastTime
        $LastLogin = (New-TimeSpan -Start $Signin -End $TodaysDate).Days
        if ($lastLogin -gt $Days){
            Remove-MgUser -UserId $User.Id -WhatIf #REMOVE BEFORE PROD
            Write-Host $user.DisplayName
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey Theo,

When popping this into PS the time is converted to local. 
In Azure AD it is 6/17/2021, 2:54:47 PM
in PS it is Thursday, 17 June 2021 4:54:47 AM 

Which is giving it +10 my timezone.

Comment: The other problem im facing is when running$user.signinactivity.lastsignindatetime as a whole, it wont return the value.

Comment: @AndrewWaters Please see my edit. You need the time to be converted from UTC to local time, because you are comparing with $TodaysDate, which is also Local timezone. I have added inline comments about this. About the `$user.signinactivity.lastsignindatetime` being empty, there was a [bug](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-powershell/issues/485) in Microsoft.Graph, so please check your version.

Comment: @AndrewWaters If you are running the buggy version of MS Graph, you may try this: `$lastTime =if ($user.value.SignInActivity) {$user.value.SignInActivity.LastSignInDateTime} else {$user.SignInActivity.LastSignInDateTime}` (untested)

Comment: sorry i never seen this comment and couldnt find the post hence created another.

I don't believe i am running a buggy version, I am using version 1.9.6 of the Microsoft.Graph.Users PowerShell module.