# Azure AD - LastSIgnInActivity

Tags: powershell

Working on a PS script which is causing me a bit of a pain, something i havent come across before.
In the script below, i need to pull the LastSignInActivity/SignInDateTime which seems to be a object in an object?

```
$usertype = "Guest" #Enter Guest or Member
$Days =  350 #Enter number in days
$TodaysDate = (Get-Date).ToUniversalTime()
$users = Get-MgUser -all -Property "DisplayName,userPrincipalName,SignInActivity" -Filter "UserType eq '$usertype'"

foreach ($User in $users) {

$myObject = [PSCustomObject]@{
    DisplayName     = $user.DisplayName
    UserPrincipalName = $user.UserPrincipalName
    LastSignInDateTime    = $user.SignInActivity.LastSignInDateTime
}
                           
            
}
```

However i cannot for the life of me get the LastSignInDateTime to appear.

Where am I going wrong?

Edited to show output of $users.signinactivity

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> $users.signinactivity

LastNonInteractiveSignInDateTime LastNonInteractiveSignInRequestId    LastSignInDateTime    LastSignInRequestId                 
-------------------------------- ---------------------------------    ------------------    -------------------                 
20/07/2021 11:09:28 AM           09c819c7-c6d2-4c9d-99a0-b76bd2ff8201 17/06/2021 4:54:47 AM 965a2f6e-e703-4719-a439-2858956e3e00
```

Comment: I know for the life of me it will be something stupidly simple :(

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot query our Azure, however, can you not write one user's SignInActivity into a tmp variable and inspect it? Like $tmp = $user.SignInActivity and show the output?

Comment: @Stephan,

Edited above to show the output

Comment: What happens if you cast it to a DateTime object: `[datetime]$($user.SignInActivity.LastSignInDateTime)` ? Any errors?

Comment: Also, please note that I already commented on your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72516155/azure-ad-delete-users-after-xyz-since-last-sign-in-date#comment128104430_72516468), there was a bug in Microsoft Graph that buried the `SignInActivity` property inside an extra `.Value` property. If you happen to be using that version, try `[datetime]$($user.value.SignInActivity.LastSignInDateTime)` or even `[datetime]$($user.AdditionalProperties.value.signInActivity.LastSignInDateTime)`

Comment: @Theo Sorry i never seen this comment and couldnt find the post hence created another. I don't believe i am running a buggy version, I am using version 1.9.6 of the Microsoft.Graph.Users PowerShell module.

I have tried the above however it still shows no values. There is definitely confirmed users that have values.

Comment: How strange. I'm also using v1.9.6 of the Microsoft.Graph.Users module and your script above works fine for me in our test environment. I'm assuming when the script is ran, you're using the beta profile and have the `AuditLog.Read.All` scope?

Comment: Can you try: $user.SignInActivity | Select-Object LastSignInDateTime

Comment: @NiMux,

Correct, using AuditLog.Read.All with the select-mgprofile (of the top of my head) -name beta

Answer (score 1):

Here is a version I finally got working, pieces borrowed from various other posts/sources, mostly Andrew Water's other post here: [Azure AD - Delete Users after XYZ since last sign in date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72516155/azure-ad-delete-users-after-xyz-since-last-sign-in-date#comment128104430_72516468)

This one will kick out the display name and creation date in addition since guest accounts UPNs aren't always the most readable. Handy if you need to confirm with management before removing stale accounts.

```
Connect-MgGraph -Scopes "User.Read.All","Group.ReadWrite.All","AuditLog.Read.All"
Select-MgProfile beta

$usertype = "Guest" #Enter Guest or Member

$Result=@()
$usersUPN = Get-MgUser -All -Filter "UserType eq '$usertype'" | Select  UserPrincipalName, ID, DisplayName, CreatedDateTime
foreach($user in $usersUPN)
{
    $usersignindate = Get-MgUser -UserId $user.ID -Select SignInActivity | Select -ExpandProperty SignInActivity
    $userprops = [ordered]@{
        UserPrincipalName = $user.UserPrincipalName
        DisplayName = $user.DisplayName
        LastSignInDateTime = $usersignindate.LastSignInDateTime
        CreatedDateTime = $user.CreatedDateTime
    }
    $userObj =  new-object -Type PSObject -Property $userprops
    $Result += $userObj
}
$Result |select *|export-csv c:\scripts\userlastlogin.csv
```